# php explode returns wrong value

Tags: php, mysql, explode

I'm submitting a form and inserting the valuse into my mysql db.
One of the form elements it a select with option values like 11#120#12 (id#cost#months).

I perform the following:

```
$plan = explode("#", $_POST['symb']);
$plan = $plan[0];
$cost = $plan[1];
```

and then submit to my db

```
echo $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO users (username, plan, cost) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['username'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($plan, "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($cost, "int"));
```

The problem is that $cost is getting the wrong value, instead of 120 it's getting 1 as a value. Where's the error? (the posted sql statement is only part of the actual query, for demonstration purposes only)

Comment: You are overwriting `$plan` in line 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't overwrite `$plan` with a string value before you try to extract the `$cost` from the array you originally stored in it.

Either change the first `$plan` in `$plan = $plan[0];` (and change every reference to it later in the script) or move that line so it appears after `$cost = $plan[1];`.

(I'd recommend the former option for clarity).`

Comment: Wow! I guess I should take a break for not seeing the absolutely obvious... thanks for pointing it out for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
$plan = explode('#',$_POST['symb']);
$p = $plan[0];
$cost = $plan[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

On line 2, $plan is assigned "11" (which was $plan[0]), and on line 3, $plan[1] references the second character in the string which is '1'.

The comments above already have already told you how to fix it.